# How to send commands to a UART CLI using Python and parse the returned text

Tags: python, uart, freertos

I have LiPo-Charger that is running on FreeRTOS and exposes a small command line interface via UART.

The charger's firmware and manual are located [here](https://github.com/AlexKlimaj/LiPow-Firmware). Note that I am not the developer of this device an that I have little experience with the hardware side of UART and FreeRTOS. Feel free to ask all sorts of complex questions, but I problably won't be able to answer them.

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian 10 lite.
When I connect it to the RPi via GPIO 14 and 15 and run a serial console application, using e.g.

`cu -l /dev/ttyS0 -s 921600`

, I can properly connect the device's CLI

```
pi@dronebox:~ $ cu -l /dev/ttyS0 -s 921600
Connected.
```

and execute queries. In the following, I execute `help` and `stats`

```
>help

help:
 Lists all the registered commands


stats:
 Displays a table showing the system stats

cal:
 Calibrates the ADC based on a known input voltage. Expects one argument as a float in milivolts. Connect input voltage to cells 1-4 and the XT60 battery output.

write_otp:
 Writes the calibration scalars to OTP flash. Will fail if scalars not set or out of range. Must run cal first with known accurate voltage. Can run up to ~32 times.

task-stats:
 Displays a table showing the state of each FreeRTOS task

run-time-stats:
 Displays a table showing how much processing time each FreeRTOS task has used

[Press ENTER to execute the previous command again]
>stats
Variable                    Value
************************************************
Battery Voltage MCU(V)       0.000
Battery Voltage Reg (V)      2.880
Charging Current (A)         0.000
Charging Power (W)           0.000
Cell One Voltage (V)         0.000
Cell Two Voltage (V)         0.000
Cell Three Voltage (V)       0.000
Cell Four Voltage (V)        0.000
2 Series Voltage (V)         0.000
3 Series Voltage (V)         0.000
4 Series Voltage (V)         0.000
MCU Temperature (C)          29
VDDa (V)                     3.291
XT60 Connected               0
Balance Connection State     0
Number of Cells              0
Battery Requires Charging    0
Balancing State/Bitmask      0
Regulator Connection State   1
Charging State               0
Max Charge Current           0.000
Vbus Voltage (V)             5.056
Input Current (A)            0.000
Input Power (W)              0.000
Efficiency (OutputW/InputW)  nan
Battery Error State          0

[Press ENTER to execute the previous command again]
>
```

This tells me that the hardware side seems to be in order.

Now, I'd like to integrate this charger into a project and constantly monitor the charging parameters, using the above shown `stats` command. For testing, I wrote a Python script, using pySerial, that is supposed to connect to the serial interface, issue the `stats` command and output the device's reply to stdout.

```
import serial
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=921600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=8, timeout=1)
print("sending...")
ser.write('help\n'.encode())
print('receiving...')
received_data = ser.read()              #read serial port
sleep(0.03)
data_left = ser.inWaiting()             #check for remaining byte
received_data += ser.read(data_left)
print (received_data.decode())
```

However, when I run this script, I get the following output:

```
sending...
receiving...
e
Command not recognized.  Enter 'help' to view a list of available commands.


[Press ENTER to execute the previous command again]
>

Command not recognized.  Enter 'help' to view a list of available commands.


[Press ENTER to execute the previous command again]
>

Command not recognized.  Enter 'help' to view a list of available commands.


[Press ENTER to execute the previous command again]
>
```

I would expect it to return the output for the `stats` command as shown above. It's also not very helpful that the interface doesn't echo the command it didn't recognize, so I can only guess that somehow my command didn't correctly arrive.

I've also tried

- sending `\r` and `\r\n` at the end of my command with the same result.
- using `.encode('utf-8')` instead of `.encode()`.
- using `b'stats'` instead of `.encode()`.

Comment: Have you tried `ser.write("help\n".encode())` using `"`.  
Alternatively ... Quoting from the documenation for the write command ` Unicode strings must be encoded (e.g. 'hello'.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @sebo1234 Yes, I tried that too by now. See my latest edit.

Comment: This question may yield more help over at [Raspberry PI](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange where folks can speak to both the programming and the physical set up to help troubleshoot further.

Comment: @itprorh66 Thanks, come to think of it, you're absolutely right. I saw this more as a python problem and forgot how closely this is related to the RPi platform.
Flagging it for migration...